# I want to set the 2nd date picker value regarding first value in jquery UI date picker

Tags: jquery

if have two date picker 1 for checkin date and other for checkout i want if i select 28-06-2012 in checkin it autmatic disable dates befor 29-06-2012 in checkout date picker 
Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getDateYymmdd(value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", value);
    }

    $('.date').datepicker({ minDate: 1, dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

    $('.date').each(function () {
        var minDdate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data(""));
        var maxDate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data("val-rangedate-max"));
        $(this).datepicker({

            maxDate: maxDate
        });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "**Jquery Ui Date picker** ", [DatePicker with Date Range Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range)

Comment: i just see it but i have to implement it in mvc3

'

Comment: i use this instead of <input>

' @Html.EditorFor(m => m.checkTextBox.checkindate)
     <br /> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.checkTextBox.checkoutdate)</th>'

Comment: can you please add more detail in your question about your mvc code ? so it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap date picket, There is some Default function defines,

I have Something Like this: 
May This helps you also

```
jQuery(".dateone").datepicker({
         dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         minDate: 1,
     });

     jQuery(".datetwo").datepicker({
         dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         minDate: new Date($('.dateone').val()),
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#frmDateStatusLog").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
          $("#toDateStatusLog").datepicker("option","minDate",$("#frmDateStatusLog").datepicker("getDate"));
    }
  });
  $( "#toDateStatusLog").datepicker({
    minDate: $("#frmDateStatusLog").datepicker("getDate")
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/2KzGS/)